# How can I track down a smell that smells like an electrical fault?

Tags: electrical, fire

For just a couple nights in the last month I've **smelled** what I thought was **plastic burning**.  Last time I recalled something similar to this, it was an extension cord in the garage that was arcing because we had put too much current through it.

Last night, *I went outside and search around*.  We do have an **electric car** that was charging, but I didn't see anything unusual or hear anything odd.  We also have **photovoltaics**, but I wouldn't expect much current to be flowing in the middle of the night!

I took out a *FLIR infrared camera*.  When there's an electrical fault and something is melting, it is usually pretty hot.  Nothing was over 21 C.  I checked the circuit breakers, the car, the charging cable and all around the outside of the house.  *No sign of fires nearby, hot spots, or arcing.*

Now **I'm pretty scared**.  I don't know if the problem is at our house or a neighbors.  I don't know if somebody was burning plastic in their fireplace or I have a short in my house.

**The ways I can think of checking it are:**

- Did the car charge normally?
- Did a circuit trip?

**What else can I check to see if it is electrical?**  Just hiring an electrician to *look around* seems a little silly.

**I can't really track how much electricity I'm using minute-by-minute, or can I?**

Comment: If you've looked all over with a FLIR camera and you're not seeing any hot spots, it's quite unlikely that anything dangerous is happening. The sort of faults that melt things also make heat.

Comment: Could easily have been a block away and just the right breeze wafted it your way.

Comment: I agree with both comments.

Comment: you could just be mirco-farcing, strokes often stink. But on a less serious note, you _can_ track your power minute by minute, just read the meter and jot down the reading now and 60 seconds from now, then multiply by 60 to get (k?)WH.

Comment: With many smart meters you can check 15-minute consumption data via your power supplier's website, without any need to fuss with buying and installing a power monitor.

Comment: Well, you didn't say you'd checked anything other than the breakers (unless they are outside, too) inside the house with the FLIR, so do that. But if that comes up empty, yeah, a nothingburger.

Comment: @Ecnerwal / The breakers are outside and so is the smell.  No smell in the garage or the house.  We can get an hourly breakdown of energy usage.  When the sun is down, that should be accurate.  When the sun is up, it is not accurate (meter runs backwards).

Comment: My supplier shows 1-hour on the website but the downloadable date also from the website is 15 minute resolution. Your supplier may, of course, vary, but I was happy to improve the resolution 4X even though it means I need to do my own charting of it.

Comment: Close all doors, wait an hour, see which room it's strongest in (if any)?

Comment: @keshlam the smell was outside of the house.  None of the rooms smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can suggest is either trying to note which way the wind is blowing when you smell it, walking the neighborhood to see if you can narrow it down, or calling your town's fire department (info number, not emergency number) and asking if anyone else has reported this. (Last time I did that was for a smell of gas; turned out I was downwind from a pumping station which is know to have occasional releases as they work on it.)

Comment: Thanks for the sympathy and suggestions.  Yeah... did all that.  Not much wind that night.  The non-emergency line didn't pick up for over 30 min, so I gave up.

Comment: Wait till it happens during working hours?  Or  tell them during working hours so might patrol can check for it for a few days?

Comment: odor has disappeared.  we've only encountered it (x2).  both times in the evening.

could just be somebody burning something bad in their fireplace, but it wasn't very cold outside.

Comment: Skunk or stinkbug or some other natural source?

Comment: Nope.  We have plenty of those nearby, so I know their odor.  It was a chlorinated smell.  The most similar smell I can think of is a burning piece of PVC pipe.

Comment: You _could_ try contacting a college with an environmental program and ask if they could lend you a student with a portable gas chromatograph. I'd say "or try a trained dog", since they can be just about as sensitive, but you need to have a sample if what they're sniffing for. Either way, unless there's a continuous low-level emission you just don't normally notice, there's nothing to track.